# Calling base class method after child class __init__ from base class __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, constructor

This is a feature I miss in several languages and wonder if anyone has any idea how it can be done in Python.

The idea is that I have a base class:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_data = 0
    def my_rebind_function(self):
        pass
```

and a derived class:

```
class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        # Do some stuff here
        self.my_rebind_function() # <==== This is the line I want to get rid of
    def my_rebind_function(self):
        # Do stuff with self.my_data
```

As can be seen above, I have a rebound function which I want called **after** the `Child.__init__` has done its job. And I want this done for all inherited classes, so it would be great if it was performed by the base class, so I do not have to retype that line in every child class.

It would be nice if the language had a function like `__finally__`, operating similar to how it operates with exceptions. That is, it should run after all `__init__`-functions (of all derived classes) have been run, that would be great. So the call order would be something like:

```
Base1.__init__()
...
BaseN.__init__()
LeafChild.__init__()
LeafChild.__finally__()
BaseN.__finally__()
...
Base1.__finally__()
```

And then object construction is finished. This is also kind of similar to unit testing with `setup`, `run` and `teardown` functions.

Comment: you want to override this method in the children classes ?

Comment: No, I want another function called after all the children's __init__-functions have been called.

Comment: You could do that with a metaclass, albiet more complex  :\

Comment: If you put the `self.my_rebind_function()` **in the base class** `__init__()`, it will call the derived class version of `my_rebind_function()` when it has been called by the derived class's `__init__()`.

Comment: @martineau: yes sure, but that is not what I want. I want it called **after** the derived class `__init__`-method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a metaclass like that:

```
    class Meta(type):
        def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            print("start Meta.__call__")
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            instance.my_rebind_function()
            print("end Meta.__call__\n")
            return instance


    class Base(metaclass=Meta):
        def __init__(self):
            print("Base.__init__()")
            self.my_data = 0

        def my_rebind_function(self):
            pass


    class Child(Base):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            print("Child.__init__()")

        def my_rebind_function(self):
            print("Child.my_rebind_function")
            # Do stuff with self.my_data
            self.my_data = 999


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        c = Child()
        print(c.my_data)
```

By overwriting Metaclass.__call__ you can hook after all __init__ ( and __new__) methods of the class-tree have run an before the instance is returned. This is the place to call your rebind function. To understand the call order i added some print statements. The output will look like this:

```
start Meta.__call__
Base.__init__()
Child.__init__()
Child.my_rebind_function
end Meta.__call__

999
```

If you want to read on and get deeper into details I can recommend following great article: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/

Comment: This does not seem to work in some cases where the __new__ method has also been overriden in the metaclass (the __call__ method never seems to get called in that case, at least I think I could provide an example), any clue or workaround for that case?

Answer (score 2):

I may still not fully understand, but this seems to do what I (think) you want:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Base.__init__() called")
        self.my_data = 0
        self.other_stuff()
        self.my_rebind_function()

    def other_stuff(self):
        """ empty """

    def my_rebind_function(self):
        """ empty """

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()

    def other_stuff(self):
        print("In Child.other_stuff() doing other stuff I want done in Child class")

    def my_rebind_function(self):
        print("In Child.my_rebind_function() doing stuff with self.my_data")

child = Child()
```

Output:

```
Base.__init__() called
In Child.other_stuff() doing other stuff I want done in Child class
In Child.my_rebind_function() doing stuff with self.my_data
```

Comment: This solves the problem and is quite nice, but there is one issue with this solution. Now I have to have the `other_stuff`-method, which is really a replacement for the `__init_`-method in the `Child`-class. So, now the user of the `Child`-class has to move code from its normal place (`__init__`), to some new method (`other_stuff`)..

Comment: The _user_ of the Child-class won;t be writing any of its code. The implementer of it will simply have to put the needed code in a different place (method). Doesn't sound like a big deal to me...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "rebind" function to be invoked after each instance of a type which inherits from `Base` is instantiated, then I would say this "rebind" function can live outside the `Base` class(or any class inheriting from it).

You can have a factory function that gives you the object you need when you invoke it(for example `give_me_a_processed_child_object()`). This factory function basically instantiates an object and does something to it before it returns it to you.

Putting logic in `__init__` is not a good idea because it obscures logic and intention. When you write `kid = Child()`, you don't expect many things to happen in the background, especially things that act on the instance of `Child` that you just created. What you expect is a fresh instance of `Child`.

A factory function, however, transparently does something to an object and returns it to you. This way you know you're getting an already processed instance.

Finally, you wanted to avoid adding "rebind" methods to your `Child` classes which you now you can since all that logic can be placed in your factory function.